# Not able to call RestEasy Url

Tags: rest, maven, jakarta-ee

I am new to RestFul API. I have a sample Project which uses Maven. Am using Jboss server to deploy.

Problem is file is deployed but when i try to access the URl it says 404 error

url : http://localhost:8080/RESTEasy/rest/RESTEasyHelloWorld/data

There is no error in Console

Following are my files:
pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTEasy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>RESTEasy</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
            </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Rest Java file:

```
package com.rest;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/RESTEasyHelloWorld")
public class RESTEasyHelloWorldService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{pathParameter}")
    public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("pathParameter") String pathParameter
            ) {

        String response = "Hello from: " + pathParameter;

        return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
    }
}
```

Server Log:

```
 08:51:54,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: 
Starting deployment of "RESTEasy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name: "RESTEasy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")

        08:51:54,300 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: 
    Replaced deployment "RESTEasy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" with deployment "RESTEasy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Comment: 1) The app needs to be deployed in a war (with the correct webapp structure) not a jar. 2) If you don't change the final name, the war will have the `-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` suffix, which will be needed in the path. You could add `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` to the `<build>` in the pom and that would just make the war the project name.

Comment: I guess that was the problem. Works fine now thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The app needs to be deployed in a war (with the correct webapp structure) not a jar.
2. If you don't change the final name, the war will have the `-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` suffix, which will be needed in the path. You could add `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>` to the `<build>` in the pom and that would just make the war the project name